# Question about definition of degree of a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Studing the theory of Riemann surfaces i've found the definition of the degree of a holomorphic map between compact Riemann Surfaces.
If i take two complex algebraic projective surfaces and a morphism between them, is there a way to extend the definition of degree between Riemann Surfaces to degree between projective surfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly general  definition of degree is associated to a **finite, dominant** morphism $f:X\to Y$ of irreducible varieties.
The definition is:   $$\operatorname {deg} (f)=[\operatorname {Rat}(X):\operatorname {Rat}(Y)]$$  Dominance ensures that $f$ gives rise to  a field morphism $f^*:\operatorname {Rat}(Y) \hookrightarrow\operatorname {Rat}(X)$ and finiteness ensures that the resulting field extension is finite.
Notice that projectiveness and dimension two ("surfaces") are irrelevant.